# What cause to error: Could not load file or assembly '' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, dll, x86, 64-bit

I working on web project I use VS2013.In solution I have 2 projects the build platform target of all projects in solution is `Any CPU`.

When I start the solution at some point in `Global.asax` file I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'MapGuideDotNetApi' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

While all DLL's and dependencies are in bin folder.

If in visual studio I check option in tools->Options->Projects and Solutions->Web Projects-> `Use the 64 bit version of IIS` I don't get any error.

My question is any idea why I get the error above?

Comment: what is MapGuideDotNetApi ?

Comment: @YashveerSingh it's dll of open source that I use.

Comment: Do you have a 32-bit version of that DLL? I suspect not.

Comment: @CodyGray they are all 64 bit

Comment: Well, then that is the problem. You say everything works correctly if you explicitly use the 64-bit version of IIS. But otherwise, it launches the 32-bit version of IIS, doesn't find a 32-bit version of the required DLL, and things fail.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your web.config, it should contain the assembly in `runtime` xml node

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration> 
<!--whatever goes here-->
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MapGuideDotNetApi" publicKeyToken="some token" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="some old version" newVersion="some new version" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <!--other assemblies-->
    </assemblyBinding>
    <!--whatever-->
</runtime>
<!--whatever goes here-->
</configuration>
```

To let the assembly appear here, I would recommend to remove and add reference which is broken.

Comment: When I add block <runtime> to webconfig I get this error:

Application Configuration file "Web.config" is invalid. Some attributes of the assemblyIdentity element are incorrect.

Comment: it should be added automatically when you add reference to the project

Comment: Could you provide more info? stack trace maybe? how it is used, some functions?